# Relative urls and .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My .htaccess file looks like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mainsite/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

all my images within the page content use relative paths like uploads/dir1/image.png.

URLs to the images have additional pseudo directories in their paths like the following example.
http://mydomain.com/mainsite/page/Contact-us/uploads/dir1/image.png
and it should be:
http://mydomain.com/mainsite/uploads/dir1/image.png

I don't want to create absolute urls, or adding `<base href="/">` the reason being when transferring site from local to remote server all urls will be lost.

Is there a way to do it with mod_rewrite?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rewrite rule to fix images path:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mainsite/

RewriteRule /(uploads/.+)$ $1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```